# PostgreSQL: FULL JOIN, проблема с выводом ids из двух таблиц

Tags: sql, postgresql

Я пробую получить такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для этого использую FULL OUTER JOIN ON id_1 = id_2, но получаю такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как составить правильно запрос?

Полный реальный запрос выглядит так:

```
WITH cte_1 AS (
SELECT
    md5(bridge_user_model_web_platform."GLOBAL_USER_ID")  AS global_user_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT fact_comment_creation.comment_key ) AS "comment_count"
FROM DATA_WAREHOUSE.PROD.FACT_CONTENT_CREATION
   AS fact_content_creation
LEFT JOIN DATA_WAREHOUSE.PROD.DIM_CONTENT_COMMENT  AS dim_content_comment ON fact_content_creation.content_key = dim_content_comment.content_key
LEFT JOIN DATA_WAREHOUSE.PROD.FACT_COMMENT_CREATION
   AS fact_comment_creation ON dim_content_comment.comment_key = fact_comment_creation.comment_key
LEFT JOIN DATA_WAREHOUSE.PROD.DIM_WEB_PLATFORM_USER  AS dim_web_platform_user ON fact_comment_creation.web_platform_user_key = dim_web_platform_user.web_platform_user_key
LEFT JOIN DATA_WAREHOUSE.PROD.BRIDGE_USER_MODEL_WEB_PLATFORM   AS bridge_user_model_web_platform ON dim_web_platform_user.web_platform_user_key = (bridge_user_model_web_platform."WEB_PLATFORM_USER_KEY")
WHERE ((( fact_comment_creation.commented_at  ) >= ((CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/New_York', 'America/Los_Angeles', CAST(DATEADD('day', -29, DATE_TRUNC('day', CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Los_Angeles', 'America/New_York', CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ)))) AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ)))) AND ( fact_comment_creation.commented_at  ) < ((CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/New_York', 'America/Los_Angeles', CAST(DATEADD('day', 30, DATEADD('day', -29, DATE_TRUNC('day', CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Los_Angeles', 'America/New_York', CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ))))) AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ))))))
GROUP BY
    1
ORDER BY
    2 DESC   
    ), cte_4 AS (
SELECT
    md5(bridge_user_model_web_platform."GLOBAL_USER_ID")  AS global_user_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT fact_conversation_creation."CONVERSATION_KEY" ) AS "conversation_count"
FROM DATA_WAREHOUSE.PROD.FACT_CONVERSATION_CREATION  AS fact_conversation_creation
LEFT JOIN DATA_WAREHOUSE.PROD.FACT_MESSAGE_CREATION  AS fact_message_creation ON (fact_conversation_creation."CONVERSATION_KEY") = fact_message_creation.conversation_key
LEFT JOIN DATA_WAREHOUSE.PROD.DIM_WEB_PLATFORM_USER  AS dim_web_platform_user ON fact_message_creation.web_platform_user_key = dim_web_platform_user.web_platform_user_key
LEFT JOIN DATA_WAREHOUSE.PROD.BRIDGE_USER_MODEL_WEB_PLATFORM   AS bridge_user_model_web_platform ON dim_web_platform_user.web_platform_user_key = (bridge_user_model_web_platform."WEB_PLATFORM_USER_KEY")
WHERE ((( fact_conversation_creation."CONVERSATION_CREATED_AT"  ) >= ((CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/New_York', 'America/Los_Angeles', CAST(DATEADD('day', -29, DATE_TRUNC('day', CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Los_Angeles', 'America/New_York', CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ)))) AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ)))) AND ( fact_conversation_creation."CONVERSATION_CREATED_AT"  ) < ((CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/New_York', 'America/Los_Angeles', CAST(DATEADD('day', 30, DATEADD('day', -29, DATE_TRUNC('day', CONVERT_TIMEZONE('America/Los_Angeles', 'America/New_York', CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ))))) AS TIMESTAMP_NTZ))))))
GROUP BY
    1
ORDER BY
    2 DESC
    ), cte_14 AS (
SELECT cte_1.global_user_id,
             "comment_count",
             "conversation_count"

FROM cte_1
FULL OUTER JOIN cte_4 AS cte_4 ON cte_1.global_user_id = cte_4.global_user_id
)

SELECT *
FROM cte_14
```

Comment: А этот grobal_user_id откуда получается ? небось из какой то одной таблицы ? Лучше запрос целиком покажите, сам факт использования full join ни о чем не говорит

Comment: Добавил в описание вопроса полный запрос.

Comment: Ну вот вы явно выбираете cte_1.global_user_id. Когда в первой таблице нет записи то в этом поле у вас будет null. сделайте coalesce(cte_1.global_user_id, cte_4.global_user_id) что бы он и из второй таблицы мог его брать

Answer (score 0):

Добавил в результат

```
coalesce(cte_1.global_user_id, cte_4.global_user_id)
```

Можно было также сделать:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN col_a IS NULL THEN col_b
          WHEN col_b IS NULL THEN col_a
          ELSE col_a || col_b
       END;
```